# How to retain border-bottom on Bootstrap dynamic navbar tabs when pulling right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-float, navbar

Does anyone have a CSS solution to make the bottom-border on Bootstrap dynamic tabs stay in place when moving the tabs from left "float" to right "float"?

`<ul class="nav nav-tabs">`

[image]

`<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right">`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the basic bootstrap tabs and only added one update to the css and the border did not disappear.  Here is a fork of a useful bootply I found when working to do tabs on the right of the container:

http://www.bootply.com/4WECvfhsko

Here is the bootply with just the basic tabs floated left:

http://www.bootply.com/cjFJup6puA

Notice I added the css above the comment that floats the list-items to the right.

```
.nav-tabs > li {
  float: right;
}
```

Is there a particular browser in which you are experiencing this?  Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Tried all browsers, latest & greatest -- PC: IE 11, Safari 5.1.7, Firefox 41.0.2, Chrome 46.0, Opera 33.0 | Macbook: Safari 9.0.1, Chrome 46.0

Comment: @H. Ferrence - Did you look at the bootply I sent?  Did you float the <ul> or the descendant <li>?  Can you provide your markup and associated CSS in a bootply?  Here is a cleaner bootply with just the basic tabs:  http://www.bootply.com/cjFJup6puA

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Hideous1. All I needed to do afterwards was to re-sort my `<li>` list items to get the tabs to appear in the order I want them.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!!